# Tensorflow for simple geometry detection

Tags: tensorflow

I've developed a rather simple polygon detection utility using OpenCV for (almost) rectangular shapes, circles, triangles. The algorithms are really simple, e.g. detect if the corners have 90° (+- tolerance) and assume it's a rectangle.

This was long ago. Now the geometries I need to detect may be irregularly shaped rectangles, or polygons.

Can you suggest me how to detect simple geometric shapes with tensorflow? In paerticular, what do you suggest how I should create the training model for such simple types (I'm guessing simple also means too much excess recognition)?

Comment: see this answer for a place to start; https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn